# Cannot resolve symbol in some classes

Tags: android, android-studio

My imported project has errors importing common classes. For example in Context.java, the following lines (there are more in other classes) are in red and give the message "Cannot resolve symbol: 'lastPartOfThePackage'"(lastPartOfThePackage being AttrRes, IntDef, DisplayAdjustments, etc.):

Trying to solve the problem, I have tried everything I have read in other SO questions, but I keep getting the errors:

- Invalidated cache and restarting.
- Installed SDK Build Tools, SDK Tools, SDK Platform-Tools
- Installed API 23 and API 16 SDKs (including the Google APIs)
- Deleted .iml and idea folder and reimported the project
- Cleaned, synced and rebuilded the project.
- Deleted both "proguardFiles" lines from build.gradle

I also checked in my sdk folder for a annotations.jar file, and it's there.

What am I doing wrong? I have worked hard trying to solve it but I don't think I'm capable enough to fix it.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" -- you appear to be attempting to include a platform copy of `Context.java` in your app. `DisplayAdjustments`, for example, is not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: Yep, I'm not able to find DisplayAdjustments either, how did you get to that?

Comment: @Fabio it's in my SDK api 23 sources

Comment: can you show us your build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

By default this should be included with appcompat, but try to add to your dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
```

and sync Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

biuld->clean project it would help.

Answer (score 0):

That is because of @hide in android source code. Actually Android is not allowing developers to use some classes.
check your SDK API source code for @hide.
 A solution is to use modified SDK which contains hidden classes. you can find it here https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api